# Finding ancestors in Wisconsin from 1871 and onwards?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, immigration, wisconsin

I am looking for my ancestors who migrated from Gunnarskog, Sweden to Milwaukee, Wisconsin, USA (their end destination) in 1871, namely:

- Marta Nilsdotter (born 1818)
- Simon Jansson (husband, born 1815)
- Anna Simonsdotter (daughter, born 1840)
- Anna's daughter Marta Andersdotter (born 1864)
- Marta Simonsdotter (daughter, born 1843)
- Anders Simonsson (son, born 1851)
- Magnus Simonsson (son, born 1858)
- Lisa Simonsdotter (daughter, born 1864)

I have found out that most of them went by Nymphen from Christiania (Norway) and arrived in Quebec on April 28, 1871. But I can't find them in the archives. I would be grateful for information on their future life in Wisconsin (or elsewhere).

Comment: Hi Marianne, welcome! I've made a few formatting edits so the list appears properly. On this site, specific questions are likely to get the best answers. If you could narrow down the question to tracing a certain type of record – e.g. marriage, death, census, probate, immigration records, etc. – that would be very helpful, because as it stands the question appears to be asking someone to research everything about each of these individuals on the list (which is too broad for this site). Alternatively you could focus just on one of these individuals for this question, and later ask about others.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I also encourage you to 1) find a specific question to ask rather than 'anything I can find' and 2) add to your post a brief statement of **how** you learned the information you've stated.  There is information in the [help] which can guide you, such as how to write a question which is [on-topic](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It's also a good idea to take the [tour] so you can get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: When you say "I can't find them in the archives", what archives are you looking in?  Perhaps your question can be focussed on something like "Finding record of Marta Nilsdotter, Simon Jansson and family in Quebec soon after 1871 when missing from <archive X>?"  Is Nymphen the name of a ship or a place?

Comment: At least one of these dates seems wrong - Lisa was baptised in 1849